# WinDBG command "!error" not work correctly?

Tags: windows, windbg

When i use !error command to show error details in windbg, it seems doesn't work...

[image]

also, i tried .locale ".1251" someone notified, it didn't work too.

[image]

so, can someone tell me, how to fix it out.

i debuged this issue, it seems error message is not printable, so message has been modified to space character. but i have no idea how to fix it...

Comment: Which version of WinDbg? Is Chinese the language of your Windows?